# List all nodes by logged in user in a custom module

Tags: views, 7

I am creating a module in Drupal 7, where I need to have a list of all nodes created by a logged in user of specific content type. How can I achieve this? It is easy to do it in view but I need to do it in a custom module. Can anybody help?

Thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome. Why not to simply use the same query views generates? What's your actual problem? I don't think we can provide full step by step module creation how to, so please tell us where you encountered a problem.

Comment: This http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/edu/drupal-7/views-module-tutorial/display-view-sql-query will help you to enable and display queries with view output..

Answer (score 1):

There is module available https://drupal.org/project/usercontent still if you want to do it in custom module then here is the code:

`global $user;
  $node_query = db_select('node', 'n') 

  ->fields('n',array('nid'))

  ->condition("type", "node type")

  ->condition("uid", $user->uid)

  $node_result = $node_query->execute()->fetchAll();`